# Arduino Code Formatting Etiquette

Tags: arduino, code-formatting

I've recently started working with an Arduino and I was wondering what the general formatting etiquette is around the `.ino` file type. For instance should something be formatted like this:

`foo ( arg1, arg2 );`
or 
`foo(arg1,arg2);`

Another example. Should curly brackets be done like this:

```
if ( value == value2 ) {
}
```

or

```
if ( value == value2)
{
}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: IMO there's not a specific coding style for Arduino. There are good pratic tips for C/C++ . Some nice Wiki links: [Coding_conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) , [Coding_Style](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Coding_Style)

Comment: If you're using the arduino IDE, it has an auto-format option (CTRL+T), so it may be a good idea to just use that and not put too much thought into it.